# how to make http://abcd.com/../../xyz/a.do work

Tags: php

I tried to run something like this http://abcd.com/../../xyz/a.do via browser.But it didn't succeed.
My question is can we run a url where it is fetching data from directories not child of abcd.com

Thanks

Edit:
Let say I have this directory structure under /www/:
    /xzy
    /blah/abcd.com/

And I want to access data in /xyz

Comment: Are you referring to faking a host to point to a directory? It's hard to understand your problem.

Comment: you can use your PHP to fetch such data. But you will do yourself HUGE favor if describe your real goal with actual data examples, real dir names and such

Answer (score 4):

No.

Relative URIs are resolved into absolute URIs by the client. `../` just causes the previous directory to be dropped. If there isn't one, then the `../` is ignored.

It would be a pretty major security problem if a web server could be instructed to fetch arbitrary content from above the web root.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very old security exploit (directory traversal) that actually worked some years ago. Nowadays, web servers are not susceptible to that.